# ruby collect first and last word from string

Tags: ruby

I have an array of strings with each string having arbitrary words and an arbitrary number of words. For each string, I need to collect only the first and last words. I can do first or last with:

```
a = vs.split("\n").
    select { |i| i =~ /^\s+\d/ }.
    collect { |i| i.scan(/\w+/).<first or last> }
```

but not for both first and last. Any suggestions?

Comment: please give some sample input and expected output also.. Only code doesn't make sense..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Array#values_at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-values_at) should do the trick:

```
str = "a b c d e"
str.scan(/\w+/).values_at(0, -1)
#=> ["a", "e"]
```

Comment: Nice - another Ruby method (`values_at`) I didn't know about!

Comment: It does not work if the string has special characters. The split() method solves that problem. For instance, "Cagão do Caraças".split(' ').values_at(0, -1)

Comment: You can use `/[[:alpha:]]+/` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the below also:

```
str = "I am a boy"
[str[/^\w+/],str[/\w+$/]]
# => ["I", "boy"]
```